# Is it typical native speaker usage to inconsistently use the pronoun "one" in a paragraph?

Tags: pronouns, word-usage, idioms

[NB: This is a re-post of a closed question that was rightly judged "off topic". It does present an interesting problem, though, so I've rewritten it and asked an on-topic usage question.]

Is it typical native-speaker usage to inconsistently use the pronoun "one" in a paragraph?

For example, in the following paragraph, **one** is often replaced by other pronouns, *viz.*, **you/your** and **we/our**. I'd like to replace these inconsistent pronouns with either **one/one’s** or **you/your**. Which of my two revisions ([2] and [3]) is more idiomatic and natural?

> [1] **One** needs to be very careful about discarding **our** old cell phones because **you** may leave behind information that **one** thinks that **they** have erased. **You** never want to find that **one’s** bank account has been drained because someone uncovered **our** PIN number and **one** certainly wouldn’t want **your** boss to find their competitor's phone number. Fortunately, there are precautions **we** can take if **one** wants to avoid these problems.**
>
> [2] **One** needs to be very careful about discarding **one’s** old cell phones, because **one** may leave behind information **one** thinks **one** has erased. **One** never wants to find that **one’s** bank account has been drained because someone uncovered **one’s** PIN number, and **one** certainly wouldn’t want **one’s** bosses to find their competitor's phone number. Fortunately, there are precautions **one** can take if **one** wants to avoid these problems.**

versus

> [3] **You** need to be very careful about discarding **your** old cell phones, because **you** may leave behind information **you** think **you** have erased. **You** never want to find that **your** bank account has been drained because someone uncovered **your** PIN number, and **you** certainly wouldn’t want **your** bosses to find their competitor's phone number. Fortunately, there are precautions **you** can take if **you** want to avoid these problems.**

Comment: One is unconvinced that "typical native-speaker usage" is a useful way to phrase the question. Devoid of any context, the answer is clearly "No, it is atypical." However one finds it difficult to accept the implicit assertion that all native speakers are alike.

Comment: @Fortriter: Non-native speakers aren't quite as aware of that as native speakers are. EFL teachers always hear from students who say that their native English-speaker foreign friends endorsed blatantly ungrammatical sentences in their homework assignments, so they must be right. After all, they're native speakers. But those of us who know better know that native speakers will say anything & claim it's grammatical, acceptable, & standard just because they're native speakers & falsely believe that they have a perfect knowledge of English when all they know for sure is their idiolect.

Comment: As a non English speaker I prefer number 3! It sounds more natural to my Persian/Iranian ears! :)

Comment: @user37324: Yeah, me too. I was wondering what other native speakers had to say, though. Most people mistake kitsch for art, noise for music, tripe for poetry, & trash for novels, even in their own language. And some of things that some of the native speakers here say make me smile. I'm sure that some of my remarks about language also raise some native speakers' eyebrows. Well, each to their own.

Comment: Another possibility: "**People** need to be very careful about discarding **their** old cell phones, because **they** may leave behind information **they** think **they** have erased ..." I'd either use *"they"* or *"you"*.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely Number 3 is most natural.  This kind of advice needs to hit home and by talking *to* the reader it is more likely to do that.  Number 2 sounds forced (*maybe a laxative would help*?) in its attempt to remain distant from the reader and to what end?

Answer (score 0):

It is typical native language usage, *in any language*, to have difficulties in parallelism, losing track of all the elements presented earlier and failing to be consistent with them throughout a narrative. (it took me some work to maintain consistency there and even then I'm not sure).

This is probably also even more difficult for a non-native speaker. But native speakers aren't perfect. They make mistakes too but just different ones, those that are natural.

Comment: What is a “natural” mistake, and what is a mistake which is not “natural”? Also, I think you mean “typical native-speaker language usage” there. Otherwise, it sounds like you’re talking about the indigenous peoples of this or that tropical island. :)

Comment: @tchrist: 'natural' means ... circularly, what a native speaker would do.